Firebase Storage: Dart library 'dart:html' is not available on this platform
I'm running into a perplexing error that occurs when I try to add Firebase Remote Config to my project.
Here is my list of dependencies:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  tuple: ^2.0.1
  http: ^0.13.6
  firebase: ^9.0.3
  provider: ^6.0.5
  google_sign_in: ^6.1.6
  firebase_core: ^2.11.0
  image_picker: ^0.8.7+4
  file_picker: ^5.3.0
  syncfusion_flutter_pdf: ^21.2.4
  path: ^1.8.2
  shared_preferences: ^2.1.1
  universal_io: ^2.2.0
  flutter_dotenv: ^5.0.2
  flutter_timer_countdown: ^1.0.5
  rive: ^0.11.4
  path_provider: ^2.1.1
  flutter_email_sender: ^6.0.1
  csv: ^5.0.2
  logging_flutter: ^3.0.0
  logging: ^1.2.0
  permission_handler: ^11.0.0
  mockito: ^5.4.2
  fl_chart: ^0.64.0
  intl: ^0.18.1
  rxdart: ^0.27.7
  introduction_screen: ^3.1.12
  fluttertoast: ^8.2.4
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.9
  dropdown_search: ^5.0.6
  percent_indicator: ^4.2.3
  animated_button: ^0.2.0
  animated_radio_buttons: ^1.0.0
  matertino_radio: ^1.0.4
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
  adapty_flutter: ^2.7.1
  adapty_ui_flutter: ^2.0.5
  multi_dropdown: ^2.0.0
  choice: ^2.3.0
  quiver: ^3.2.1
  lottie: ^2.7.0
  vibration: ^1.8.4
  collection: ^1.17.2
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.3.7
  url_launcher: ^6.2.4
  tutorial_coach_mark: ^1.2.11
  selectable: ^0.3.0
  animated_item_picker: ^2.0.0
  flutter_ioc_container: ^1.0.12
  ioc_container: ^1.0.12
  sign_in_with_apple: ^5.0.0
  firebase_analytics: ^10.10.1
  flutter_getit: ^2.0.0
  get_it: ^7.6.9
  mocktail: ^1.0.3
  firebase_auth: ^4.19.1
  timeago: ^3.6.1
  firebase_storage: ^11.7.2
  cloud_firestore: ^4.17.0
  loggy: ^2.0.3
  animated_bottom_navigation_bar: ^1.3.3
  cloud_functions: ^4.7.3
  youtube_player_flutter: ^9.0.1
  flutter_animate: ^4.5.0
  firebase_app_check: ^0.2.2+5
  firebase_remote_config: ^4.4.6

What I've tried so far:

Removing Firebase Remote Config unfortunately does not fix the problem, nor does reinstalling Firebase Storage
Deleting AppData/Local/Pub/Cache
Deleting ./dart-tools/flutter_build/<hash>
Deleting ./build/<hash>
Running flutter clean; flutter pub get

I don't know if it's relevant, but the same two hashes are always produced in ./dart-tools/flutter_build/<hash> and ./build/<hash>.
This is the full error log:
Pastebin since log is too long

you are running it on mobile?

Yes, tried two different emulators so far.

find out where you have import dart:html and delete that line.

It's in the Firebase Flutter plugin, I've tried deleting them in two places but more errors of the same kind just keep popping up, including a JavaScript import, and now the error is that the code can't find the libraries I've deleted. This definitely seems like Firebase is trying to run in Web when it's not supposed to.

The answer was that firebase, which is the origin of the error in the stacktrace, is a deprecated plugin. firebase_core is supposed to be used.
